# Is there a way to define an indexable type in golang?

Tags: go, indexing, types

I recently came across a library that does graph processing by direct indexing i.e `graph[key]`, I have a node tree which has its child nodes under a certain attribute `node.childs[key]`.

I was wondering if there is a way to define a type so that an attribute could be accessible through direct key mapping, such as `node[key]` would be mapped to `node.childs[key]`. Is there a way to achieve this while defining new types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do what you want. The spec does not allow it. [Spec: Index expressions:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Index_expressions)

> A primary expression of the form
>
> ```
> a[x]
> ```
>
> denotes the element of the array, pointer to array, slice, string or map `a` indexed by `x`. The value `x` is called the *index* or *map key*, respectively. The following rules apply:
>
> For `a` of [array type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Array_types) `A`: [...]
>
> For `a` of [pointer](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Pointer_types) to array type: [...]
>
> For `a` of [slice type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_types) `S`: [...]
>
> For `a` of [string type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_types): [...]
>
> For `a` of [map type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Map_types) `M`: [...]
>
> For `a` of [type parameter type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_parameter_declarations) `P`: [...]
>
> **Otherwise `a[x]` is illegal.**

Only these listed types are indexable, no other. And you can't even change the meaning of the index operator ([you can't override it](https://go.dev/doc/faq#overloading)).